# How return ID or all from another class with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, class

I learning Entity Framework, so don't blame me if this is easy for you

I have class **HomeNumber.cs**

```
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key]
    public int HomeNumberId { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("HomeNumberId")]
    //public virtual HomeNumber HomeNumbers { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Polje kućni broj je obavezno!")]
    public string HomeNumberName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Polje pod broj/slovo je obavezno!")]
    public string HomeSubNumber { get; set; }

    public int StreetId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StreetId")]
    public virtual Street Street { get; set; }

    ....

    public bool AddHomeNumber(string homeNumberName, string homeSubNumber, Street street)
    {
        HomeNumber number = new HomeNumber();
        number.HomeNumberName = homeNumberName;
        number.HomeSubNumber = homeSubNumber;
        number.StreetId = street.StreetId;

        using (var _db = new DataContext())
        {
            // Dodaj HomeNumber u bazu [AD_HOMENUMBER]
            _db.DB_HomeNumber.Add(number);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        // Success.
        return true;
    }
```

And class Street.cs

```
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key]
    public int StreetId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Polje naziv ulice je obavezno!")]
    public string StreetName { get; set; }

    .....

    public bool AddStreet(string streetName)
    {
        Street street = new Street();
        street.StreetName = streetName;

        using (var _db = new DataContext())
        {
            // Dodaj Street u bazu [AD_STREET]
            _db.DB_Street.Add(street);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        // Success.
        return true;
    }
```

My behind code is:

```
    Street st = new Street();
    st.AddStreet(ucAddress.Street.Text);

    HomeNumber hou = new HomeNumber();
    hou.AddHomeNumber(ucAddress.HouseNumber.Text, ucAddress.HouseSubNumber.Text, st.StreetId);
```

I need in my behind code **st.streetId** with value,... I don't know what i missing,... Because in **AddHomeNumber** i calling **street.StreetId** where is return value from **st.streetId**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do on `AddStreet` looks like this. You save the `Street` and return the result.

```
public Street AddStreet(string streetName)
{
    Street street = new Street();
    street.StreetName = streetName;

    using (var _db = new DataContext())
    {
        // Dodaj Street u bazu [AD_STREET]
        _db.DB_Street.Add(street);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    // Success.
    return street;
}
```

In code behind you have pass `st` not `st.StreetId` in `AddHomeNumber`.

```
Street st = new Street();
st = st.AddStreet(ucAddress.Street.Text); // get the street that has been saved with generated id.

HomeNumber hou = new HomeNumber();
hou.AddHomeNumber(ucAddress.HouseNumber.Text, ucAddress.HouseSubNumber.Text, st);
```

**Note:** I recommend you to take a look on *Repository pattern*, will make your life easier and you will write more readable and awesome code.

---

A basic repository for `Street` will look like this also for `HomeNumber` or other entities you create a *Repository* in the same manner.

```
public class StreetRepository 
{
    private DataContext _db;
    public StreetRepository(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        _db = dataContext;
    }

    public Street Add(string streetName)
    {
        Street street = new Street();
        street.StreetName = streetName;

        using (var _db = new DataContext())
        {
            // Dodaj Street u bazu [AD_STREET]
            _db.DB_Street.Add(street);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        // Success.
        return street;
    }

    public Street Get(int id)
    {
        return _db.DB_Street.Find(id);
    }

    // other CRUD methods
}
```

Usage:

```
StreetRepository streetRepository = new StreetRepository();
HomeNumberRepository homeNumberRepository = new HomeNumberRepository(); // you have to create it yourself

Street st = streetRepository.Add(ucAddress.Street.Text); // get the street that has been saved with generated id.

HomeNumber homeNumber = homeNumberRepository.Add(ucAddress.HouseNumber.Text, ucAddress.HouseSubNumber.Text, st);
```

**Note:** You may find it painfull to write a *Repository* for every *Entity*, here come in helps *generic Repositories*.

After you master the *Repository pattern* you can go to the *Unit Of Work* and to discover that *EntityFramework* already have it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information! You help me totally :)
And thank you for information about Repository Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Diffrent approach

```
public int AddStreet(string streetName)
{
    Street street = new Street();
    street.StreetName = streetName;

    using (var _db = new DataContext())
    {
        // Dodaj Street u bazu [AD_STREET]
        _db.DB_Street.Add(street);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    // Success.
    return street.StreetId;
}
```

and in code behind

```
int pStreetId = 0;
Street st = new Street();
pStreetId = st.AddStreet(ucAddress.Street.Text);

HomeNumber hou = new HomeNumber();
hou.AddHomeNumber(ucAddress.HouseNumber.Text, ucAddress.HouseSubNumber.Text, pStreetId);
```

What is missing by you is that id is added to objct when you save it, that's it.